# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS no sound after apt-get upgrade

Tags: sound

[image]My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop, it was working fine initially.I just did an apt-get upgrade, after that on  with sound. Any ideal how to fix this ?

Thanks
Updated on 2018-02-09.

[image]
The bluetooth  device was lost. Select HMDI, to test sound. No  sound played.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soundcard driver packages could not have been properly installed. Reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: @user1121055 It is good that your response towards an answer. So you need to accept the answer by click on the accept button near the answer. So others also can get benefit from an answer.

Comment: No didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the bluedevice. Added it again and it works now.
I am very sure I did it before many times but did not work.